# Error Unhandled exception at 0x00D0345E in linkedlist.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004

Tags: c++, linked-list

I try create linked-list with n element in c++.

But I received an error message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00D0345E in linkedlist.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004.

What is the reason?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct linklist
{
    int data;
    linklist *next;
};

void Create_linklist(linklist &l,int n) // with n element
{
    linklist *phead,*p;
    int i=0;
    phead=p=NULL;
    while (i<n)
    {
        if (phead==NULL)
        {
            phead=new linklist;
            p=phead;
        }
        else
        {
            p->next=new linklist; //--> Seem error this line
            p=p->next;
        }
        cout<<"Input value "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>p->data;
        i++;
        p=p->next=NULL;
    }
}

void Outer_list(linklist l)
{
    linklist *p=new linklist;
    if (p!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<p->data<<" ";
        p=p->next;
    }
}
void main()
{
    linklist list;
    Create_linklist(list,5);
    Outer_list(list);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: can't you debug yourself?

Comment: I can't, need a help.

Comment: you need to lean how to debug before you can do anything useful

Comment: Well, i knew. I'm running debug. When i input second value, an error message show: First-chance exception at 0x009C345E in linkedlist.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004

Comment: it should also tell you which line cause the problem

Comment: Yes, error this line: p->next=new linklist; But i don't know fix it

Comment: initialize `p` before using it

Comment: You need to learn how to use a debugger. The debugger will tell you exactly what line has the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
p=p->next=NULL;
```

to this

```
p->next=NULL;
```

In your code when you get to the line

```
p->next=new linklist;
```

p is always NULL. A debugger should have told you this. In fact before you fix this code I would try to use a debugger again, and this time see how the value of p changes as you run the program. It will be a good lesson in learning how to use a debugger.